# Select all items that are in the array from db?

Tags: php, pdo

I have an array looks like this: (1, 4, 2, 3).
I want to select all threads that contains column tid, one of these numbers in the array:

```
$get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 10");
$get->execute();                    
$array = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

$new = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_posts WHERE replyto = 0 AND tid IN (:ids) LIMIT 10");
$new->execute(array(":ids" => implode(",", $array)));
```

But, it only fetches one item from the database, while I have more than one results?

Why is it doing that?

I think it only fetches the first array item, I am not to sure, but do you see anything wrong?

What I am trying to do is:

I have tabs.

The tabs shows the most popular threads, by replies .
I want to do so, when you click on the tab, it will switch to the right post.

```
<div class="container row">
    <h2>Top 10 Stories</h2>
    <div id="story-tab">
        <ul>
            <?php
            $test = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 10");
            $test->execute();

        //  while ($row = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            //{
                //echo'<li><a href="#st-'.$row['tid'].'-'.$row['fid'].'">'. $row['subject'].'</a></li>';
                echo'<li><a href="#st-1-1">1</a></li>';
                echo'<li><a href="#st-2-1">2</a></li>';
            //} 
            $get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 10");
            $get->execute();                    
            $array = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

            ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
            $test = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY replies DESC");
            $test->execute();

            $fetch = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $new = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_posts WHERE replyto = 0 AND tid IN (:ids) LIMIT 10");
            $new->execute(array(":ids" => implode(",", $array)));

            while ($row = $new->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<br /><br /><br /><br />'. $row['tid'].','.$row['fid'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <br class="clear">
    <h2>Top 10 Popular Threads</h2>
    <div id="thread-tab">

    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right here at http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php ***Example #5*** shows how to prepare a statement with an IN clause using an array of ints.  For your case, it would be...

```
$params = array(1, 21, 63, 171);
/* Create a string for the parameter placeholders filled to the number of params */
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_posts WHERE replyto = 0 AND tid IN ($place_holders) LIMIT 10"); 
$sth->execute($params); // fills the placeholder ?'s with the values of your array
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of..

```
$new->execute(array(":ids" => implode(",", $array)));
```

could you try

```
$ins= implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'));
```

and then

```
$new->prepare("SELECT *  FROM mybb_posts WHERE replyto =0 AND tid IN ($ins) LIMIT 10");
$new->execute($ins);
```